# Insert row into psql db using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
I am trying to insert a new player into the players table. 
this is the python code:

```
def registerPlayer(name):

code for connecting to db and cursor 

c.execute("INSERT INTO players(player_name) VALUES({name});".format(name=name))

code for committing to db and closing the connection
```

here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE players(
  player_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  player_name  varchar(50) NOT NULL

);
```

below is error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Nalaar" LINE 1:
```

INSERT INTO players(player_name) VALUES(Chandra Nalaar);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use string formatting for placing values into sql query. Instead, you should use `%s` and pass the name in the `vars` parameter. The reason behind doing it this way is because it helps you convert the parameters into the appropriate data types.

Btw, having a `;` at the end  in the sql string is redundant when called by `cursor.execute`, since it does it for you automatically.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO players(player_name) VALUES(%(name)s)", {"name":name})
```

See this page for further details:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: thanks a lot! it didn't show any error after I revised the code (though the last part should be {"name": name"} according to the documentation.

Comment: @rstreet you’re welcome, sorry about the typo, I typed it from my phone :p